Can't Copying ENV variables into temp file, when create database through run file createdb.sh
when I run this command
livyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$ sudo -u postgres ./createdb.sh
then i get some error
`Copying ENV variables into temp file...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/livyasusilo/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db/processenv.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)        
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 7: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 12: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 17: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
USER=
DATABASE=
tgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./explorerpg.sql: No such file or directory
could not change directory to "/home/livyasusilo/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./updatepg.sql: No such file or directory
livyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$
livyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$ NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postglivyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$ 
livyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$ sudo -u postgres ./createdb.sh
Copying ENV variables into temp file...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/livyasusilo/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db/processenv.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 7: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 12: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
./createdb.sh: line 17: [: ==: unary operator expected
jq: error: Could not open file /tmp/process.env.json: No such file or directory
USER=
DATABASE=
PASSWD=
Executing SQL scripts, OS=linux-gnu
could not change directory to "/home/livyasusilo/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./explorerpg.sql: No such file or directory
could not change directory to "/home/livyasusilo/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./updatepg.sql: No such file or directory`

why file.sh can't find the module?
livyasusilo@DESKTOP-0NIM08I:~/explorer/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db$ ls
createdb.sh  explorerpg.sql  processenv.js  updatepg.sql

it should be there if I check the directory.
And why permission denied to this directory? I already try
chmod -R 775 \db 
on postgres directory.
these files and directories should be accessible. How can I handle this errors? and create database through file createdb.sh?
